# NSPathControl setDoubleAction does not work

Tags: objective-c, nspathcontrol

I have added a `NSPathControl` to a View in my application.
In `awakeFromNib` I sets the double-click action:-

```
[currentPath setDoubleAction:@selector(dClickPath:)];
```

Unfortunately, double-click on the PathControl does not work, although I had first tested this a simple stand alone test application.

I suspect that there may be some interaction with other elements.
In particular I have a `NSSplitView` which contains a `NSOutlineView` and a `NSTableView`, both of which have Double Click Target bindings to separate selectors in the controller.

I don't see why these should affect the NSPathControl.

If I connect the `NSPathControl` selector to dClickPath: then Click on the 
PathControl works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the target? When you connect a control in IB, that sets the target and the action. If you don't do that in IB, then setting the double-click action in code is not enough. You also have to set the target.